# Profiling in Visual C++

Tags: c++, profiling

This question was asked in [Why there are contentions in places with no lockings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495987/why-there-are-contentions-in-places-with-no-lockings) but there was no answer. After using the visual c++ profiler, I found that the most expensive call path ended with zzz_AsmCodeRange_begin. Could you please tell me what this means, and if it can be optimized any further?

Thank You

Comment: When you find an expensive path through the call tree, it usually isn't the leaf that's the troublemaker. The problem is usually some one of the lines higher up the stack requesting that time to be spent.